# @Configuration in child project not working in parent

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have a parent application **Application1** which loads beans based on `Spring XML` configuration.

I have child application **Application2** (included/referred on Application1) with `@Configuration` based `fully annotated spring java` file.

When I deploy **Application1** in tomcat, I see that none of the beans from **Application2** loaded.

Am i missing anything?

I tried component-scan for **Application2** in **Application1**'s `spring XML` but no change noticed.

**Edited**
XML of Application 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

     <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.work.aspect"/>

 </beans>
```

**Package of @Configuration file:**

```
com.test.work.aspect.JMXConfiguration
```

Edit2:

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.test.aspect.mbean")
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
    @Profile("aspect")
    public class JMXConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public MyRmiRegistryFactoryBean myRmiRegistryFactoryBean(){
            return new MyRmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public MyConnectionServerFactoryBean myConnectionServerFactoryBean()    {
            return new MyConnectionServerFactoryBean();
        }
}
```

Comment: component-scan should work.  Post the XML portion containing component-scan, and the package that Application2's @Configuration file is contained in.

Comment: @IanMc Edited the question with details.

Comment: XML file looks good.  "com.test.work.aspect" should be scanned.  Can you post the configuration file containing the @Configuration annotation, to see how you define your beans?  Thank you.

Comment: @IanMc pasted Configuration file. Edited to be generic. Thank you

Comment: This looks good.  I suspect that @Profile is preventing the load.  Are you certain that "aspect" is active?  Perhaps comment out Profile line to see what happens.

Comment: @IanMc. I have another application which loads this configuration. But for this specific application in question, its not working. I am certain that profile is active. Still I would double check.

Comment: @IanMc I think it was issue with IDE. code changes not reflected even after 5 builds. Working fine now. your 3rd comment is apt.Thank you very much!